# Angular 7: add routing links from backend

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I'm trying to find a way to add route link to data retreived from backend API.
I tried to add `<a routerLink="...">...</a>` in the backend data then to use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` but it is not working.

I wonder if I have to use .html sub template or if I can manage it fully from TypeScript?

EDIT 1:
Here is the data I receive from the back:

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "result":{
      "chmn":[
         {
            "id":267,
            "number":"",
            "hanzi":"\u4e00",
            "simplified":"",
            "mnemonics":"one; <a>\u58f1<\/a> <a>\u7532<\/a>; <a>\u4f96<\/a> <a>\u4fde<\/a> <a>\ud842\udf9b<\/a> <a>\u4ee4<\/a> <a>\u5f10<\/a> <a>\u6b66<\/a> <a>\u6238<\/a> <a>\u81f3<\/a> <a>\u767e<\/a>;",
            "alike":"",
            "mine":false,
            "meaning":"",
            "reference":"",
            "remnant":false
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What I'm trying to acheive is to replace empty `<a>\u58f1<\/a>` by `<a routerLink="/details/\u58f1">\u58f1</a>` to create a dynamic route link.
But if I directly put this in the backend response, Angular will not consider it as a real router link.

EDIT 2: Thanks to Stefan, here is the solution I've used:

```
  res.result.chmn.forEach(element => {
    element.mnemonics = element.mnemonics.split(/(\p{Script=Hani})+/gu);
  });
```

and in the template:

```
<span *ngFor="let mnemonic of kanji.mnemonics">
    <span *ngIf="mnemonic.length > 1" [innerHTML]="mnemonic | sanitizeHtml"></span>
    <a *ngIf="mnemonic.length == 1" routerLink="/details/{{mnemonic}}">{{mnemonic}}</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Try to send object data from backend.

Comment: Can you share some code so we get a better idea what you want to achieve and what's not working?

Comment: I've added an example in my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have `\u58f1`, `\u4f96`... as Url parameters (yet).
Try sending your dynamic routlinks in an object structure e.g:

```
routes: { link: string, text: string }[] = [
    {
      link: "login", // a valid url string
      text: "\u58f1" // a renderable "CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH" sign
    },
    {
      link: "home",
      text: "\u4f96"
    }
  ]
```

You can then render the routs dynamically e.g. like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let route of routes">
  <a routerLinkActive="active" 
    routerLink="/{{route.link}}">{{route.text}}</a>
</div>
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-e1fpas?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad idea to receive whole anchor tab from backend like `<a>\u58f1<\/a>` . What I am understanding from your response snippet **u58f1** is an id/code.You could simply get those ids from back end and use it like 
`<a routerLink="/details/{{:id}}">` if it is possible.